# Docker Machine vs Docker run

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I'm confused between docker-machine vs docker run

docker images, shows me my images
and then I can run one of these images with docker run.

When do I need to use docker-machine?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/machine/overview/)

> You can use Docker Machine to:
>
> - Install and run Docker on Mac or Windows
> - Provision and manage multiple remote Docker hosts
> - Provision Swarm clusters

in other words:

> when your Host OS does not support running Docker Engine natively
>   (i.e. on Mac and Windows).

and basically docker run is to start a container based on a docker image either from a local image or from the online registry.

Comment: Note for those looking at this answer now, swarm cluster provisioning is classic Swarm, not the more popular Swarm Mode that is built into the docker engine.

Answer (score 10):

You would use docker-machine if you:

- Have a VirtualBox based install of Docker for Win/Mac, rather than the newer HyperV or xhyve releases.
- Have machines in the cloud that you'd like to manage from docker-machine

docker-machine includes boot2docker images to do an install and it acts as a wrapper to setting the docker environment variables to point the client to a remote host. You can easily do that latter part by hand.

Docker itself is what runs the containers, so if you're able to do that without docker-machine, you probably don't need to complicate your toolset.